# what kind of application account for application base SOA?

Tags: .net, wcf, soa

for example,I have two applications,one is internal systems for the enterprise,the other
is for dealers.In order to finish a business process both of them should collaborate each other
,such as order management,return management.I just simply add a service layer using WCF technology
to finish such requirement.I wonder whether this two applications can be called as application
base SOA? If the answer is not,then how can i satisfy  my requirement using SOA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds that you're on the right track. However, keep in mind that SOA is a whole paradigm that encompasses much more than just integration of applications. However, you can design your applications in such a way that they support future efforts in implementing SOA.

I'd recommend the following approach:

- Expose all functionality that is part of the processes as operations in standardized services. Try to make each service as universal and as autonomous as possible, in order to achieve reusability of each service in the future.
- Do not connect the two applications directly, but rather do it using a middleware solution (it doesn't have to be an ESB, it can be something much simpler at this stage). Thus, you won't couple both applications to each other, and you will be able to change the integration specifics in the middleware, without modifying both applications when one of them changes. The benefits of using intermediary layer will be much more apparent once you add more applications to your architecture that connect with your existing ones.
- Research SOA as your architecture becomes more complex. You may need to implement a BPM solution at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you have to expose the services to be used by the dealers as wcf or rest and the internal services be called from those external api calls.

Since the dealer needs to know any implementation specifics of how you handle the internal systems management its not required to expose the internal services to the dealers.

In case of a future requirement to expose additional feature, we can add to the existing external service or publish a new service.